# Getting value of a column where another column is minimum from group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

##### Input:

I have an input dataframe with text, character length, and values 'x' and 'flag':

```
    x   text    len     flag
0   1   hi      2       1
1   1   hello   5       0
2   1   how     3       1
3   2   are     3       1
4   2   you?    4       1
5   2   kiddo   5       1
```

I want to groupby 'x' and get the 'text' of lowest character length where 'flag' is 1.

##### Output:

```
    x   text    len     select
0   1   hi      2       hi
1   1   hello   5       nan
2   1   how     3       nan
3   2   are     3       are
4   2   you?    4       nan
5   2   kiddo   5       nan
```

I tried to `groupby()` and get the minimum value but how do I get the text where minimum value is present? I don't wanna use apply.

```
df[df.flag == 1].groupby('x')['len'].transform('min')
```

That'll get the min char length value, but not the actual 'text' value where char length is minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need `groupby` and `transform` with `idxmin`:

```
# Handle the `flag` requirement.
v = df.assign(len=df['len'].where(df.flag.astype(bool)))

condition = v.groupby('x')['len'].transform('idxmin')
df.loc[condition, 'select'] = df.loc[condition, 'text'].values

df
   x   text  len  flag select
0  1     hi    2     1     hi
1  1  hello    5     0    NaN
2  1    how    3     1    NaN
3  2    are    3     1    are
4  2   you?    4     1    NaN
5  2  kiddo    5     1    NaN
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. I'll now remember `idxmin` .

Comment: @Vishnudev Are you sure your edit was what you wanted to do? The result is different now.

Comment: Why do you ask that? I want other values to be nan

Comment: I have fixed the question.

Comment: @Vishnudev This is the output of your code... does that look right?